# I' beginner with Semantic Model using roslyn what are steps to get Concrete Type of TypeSymbol from TypeSyntax?

Tags: c#, symbols, roslyn

I want to get concrete Type of `TypeSyntax` .

I read that I should use Semantic Model but I don't know steps to make this.

suppose that  I make Syntax parsing and  I have variable called  mytype  of type `TypeSyntax` .

when I use `ToFullString()` Method it return string contain `"Nullable<int>"` .
I want `Nullable<int>` as type to not string  to get  properties such as `Type.IsValueType` Property

```
var a = mytype.ToFullString();  // return string contain "Nullable<int>"
```

.

Comment: Can you add an example of the source code you want to analyze and the analyzer results ?

Comment: thanks for repley .my Code is complex to explain here . only  what i want to do that  I  have variable   of type **TypeSyntax** and I wand to get concrete type of it .